# How to measure the voltage of battery while charging?

Tags: batteries, battery-charging, simulink

I want to design a battery charger. I need know the voltage of battery to calculate the state of charge (SOC) of it, but if I just put a voltage measure model in parallel, it will measure the charger voltage which from the buck circuit.

I have a idea to use a MOSFET to turn off the charge circuit when I want to measure voltage, but I don't know whether this idea is good for battery health.  Is it feasible for the real battery?

[image]

Comment: It would be more accurate to switch the charger to a 1 C load then off and measure the Voc and compare with charts to bleed off some memory charge. But normally it's done by a 1C charge CC and measure difference to CV.

Comment: What you measure at the battery terminals **is** the battery voltage, regardless of it being charged or discharged. So why do you think you need to disconnect the charger, unless you are doing something wrong like not charging the batteries correctly (which is dangerous).

Comment: Making a table with one full charging cycle on 1C starting current (on low SOC state, depending on battery type) for charge voltage (on battery or charger terminals is less important, if wire resistance is known and/or very low and maybe low 1digit A currents, but keep consistent through one cycle) and charge current on a (depending on battery's capacity) 1-5-15 minutes periods. Maybe Your measurement equipment allows for to log that parameters (You want add a temperature sensor, mandatory for some battery types and surroundings). Adjust charger at most to a top battery voltage from datasheet.

Comment: simulink battery model, explains differences for load variances and battery types https://de.mathworks.com/help/physmod/sps/powersys/ref/battery.html

Answer (score 0):

State of charge?
A lithium cell reaches 4.2V long before it is fully charged.
The charging **current** drops to a low amount when it is fully charged.

Comment: While the battery is being charged current is flowing into the battery. This is only possible if the charge voltage is higher then the battery voltage. This will raise the terminal voltage of the battery, not by much if the battery is in good shape. However as it ages its internal resistance will increase raising the terminal voltage during charge. Disconnecting the charge and reapplying it should not do any damage to the battery,